# Module & argument of complex number exp(ix) +exp(2ix)

Tags: complex-numbers

I tried unsuccessfully to solve the following complex expression and get the module and the argument.

> ${e}^{ix}+{e}^{2ix}$

I converted the whole expression to trigonometric function  cos and sin but it got more complex than it looks at the origin.

Comment: Is the module the absolute value ? Your approach is good. Why do you expect an easy formula for module and argument ?

Comment: for modulus, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362243/show-that-zz2-2-cos-frac-theta2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
e^{ix}+e^{2ix}
&=e^{\frac32ix}\left(e^{\frac12ix}+e^{-\frac12ix}\right)\\
&=e^{i\color{#090}{\frac32x}}\color{#C00}{2\cos\left(\tfrac12x\right)}
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
\left|\,e^{ix}+e^{2ix}\,\right|=\left|\,\color{#C00}{2\cos\left(\tfrac12x\right)}\,\right|
$$
and
$$
\arg\left(e^{ix}+e^{2ix}\right)\equiv\color{#090}{\tfrac32x}+\pi\left[\,\cos\left(\tfrac12x\right)\lt0\,\right]\pmod{2\pi}
$$
where $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: But $$\cos\dfrac x2$$ can be $$<0?$$

Comment: Very nice solution !

Comment: Elegant Solution . **Really** Beautiful and Beyond my **Imagin{ation}{ary}** Before I Discovered it. 
Thanks .

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: good point! I have added a correction for that

Comment: @robjohn, Thanks for the Iverson bracket which is new to me. Actually I was thinking in the same line as well.Regarding argument  I think, we need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation . For example, $x=\dfrac{17\pi}3$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: arg is always mod $2\pi$, so I have noted that, too. This way, one can handle $-\pi/4$ and $7\pi/4$ as one sees fit.

Comment: What if I use _Maclaurin_ Series. 
I got this so far:
> $e^{ix} +e^{2ix}=2+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}(1-2^{2k})}{(2k)!} +{i}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k+1}(1-2^{2k+1})}{(2k+1)!} $

Answer (score 2):

$$1+e^{ix}=1+\cos x+i\sin x=2\cos^2\frac x2+2i\cos\frac x2\sin\frac x2=2\cos\frac x2e^{ix/2}$$

so that

$$e^{ix}+e^{2ix}=2\cos\frac x2 e^{3ix/2}.$$

---

Notice that the first locus is a shifted circle, while the second is the good old Pascal's limaçon, obtained by tripling the argument.

[image]

Comment: It's really a pleasure  to read a such Gem . Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Let $$Z=e^{ix}+e^{2ix}=e^{ix}(1+e^{ix}) \Rightarrow |Z|=|1+\cos x +i \sin x|= \sqrt{1+\cos x)^2+\sin ^2x}$$ $$\Rightarrow |Z|=\sqrt{2+2\cos x}=2 \cos(x/2).$$

$$Arg(Z) =Arg[(\cos x+\cos 2x)+i(\sin x+ \sin 2x)]= \tan^{-1} \frac{\sin x+\sin 2x}{\cos x + \cos 2x}$$ $$ \Rightarrow Arg(Z)= \tan^{-1} \tan (3x/2)=3x/2.$$

Comment: Another piece of art . Elegant too.